# C - Merge two arrays in one, by their iterative positions

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem with merging two arrays in one, but I need to put one element by one, so I have following:

```
arr1[0] = 1; arr2[0] = 12;
arr1[1] = 2; arr2[1] = 20;
arr1[2] = 3; arr2[2] = 30;
arr1[3] = 4; arr2[3] = 40;
arr1[4] = 5; arr2[4] = 50;
arr1[5] = 6; arr2[5] = 60;
arr1[6] = 7; arr2[6] = 70;
arr1[7] = 8; arr2[7] = 80;
arr1[8] = 9; arr2[8] = 90;
arr1[9] = 11;arr2[9] = 100;
```

And I need to merge them in 3rd array "arr3" by sorting like:

> `arr3 = [1,12,2,20,3,30,4,40,5,50,6,60,7,70,8,80,9,90,11,100]`

This is the code I made but it's not working still:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int arr1[10], arr2[10], arr3[20], i,k,r;

    arr1[0] = 1; arr2[0] = 12; 
    arr1[1] = 2; arr2[1] = 20;
    arr1[2] = 3; arr2[2] = 30;
    arr1[3] = 4; arr2[3] = 40;
    arr1[4] = 5; arr2[4] = 50;
    arr1[5] = 6; arr2[5] = 60;
    arr1[6] = 7; arr2[6] = 70;
    arr1[7] = 8; arr2[7] = 80;
    arr1[8] = 9; arr2[8] = 90;
    arr1[9] = 11;arr2[9] = 100;

    for(i=0; i<20; i++){

        if(arr3[i-1] != 0){
            arr3[i] = arr1[i];
            arr3[i+1] = 0;
        } else {
            arr3[i-1] = arr2[i-1];
        }
        i++;

    }
    for(k=0; k<20; k++){
        printf("arr - %d b: %d \n", k, arr3[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use some `for (int i;` loop, and `arr1[i/2]` and `arr2[i/2]`

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: Without a code showing what you have tried, your question is *off-topic*

Comment: At start, `i` is 0, so `arr2[i-1]` is `arr3[-1]` which is an out-of-bound array access.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick the one you use!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr3[j++] = arr1[i];
    arr3[j++] = arr2[i];
}
```

---

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @lundin I have initialized the value for ```j``` inside ```for``` loop. Hope no edit was needed!

Comment: Oops, I didn't read carefully enough, sorry!

Comment: @Lundin It happens. No worries. :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr3[i*2] = arr1[i];
    arr3[i*2 + 1] = arr2[i];
}
```

[Try it here!](http://ideone.com/voagzr)

Your code has some failures:

```
for(i=0; i<20; i++){

    if(arr3[i-1] != 0){      // if i==0 you read arr3[-1] which is undefined behaviour
        arr3[i] = arr1[i];
        arr3[i+1] = 0;
    } else {
        arr3[i-1] = arr2[i-1];
    }
    i++;  // you have 2 times i++, one here and one in your for

}
```

If you want to check if some elements are `0` you have to initialize your array with zero:

```
arr3[20] = {0};
```

Else your if will always be undefined behaviour, because `i` is always even because of the double `i++` and you always check the uninitialized uneven elements with `arr3[i-1] != 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ****Try this:**
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0,j = 0;j <10,i < 20;i+=2,j++)
    {
        arr3[i] = arr1[j];
        arr3[i + 1] = arr2[j]; 
    }**
```

**

> ****By implementing this you can do it quickly in O(n) time for larger data insertion.****

**